# By what mechanism is NADP+ converted to NADPH in Photosystem I?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, photosynthesis

Here is my current understanding:

$\mathrm{NADP^{+}}$ takes 2 electrons from Ferredoxin at the end of the electron transport chain to generate $\mathrm{NADP^{-}}$.  An $\mathrm{H^{+}}$ ion in the stroma binds through the extra electron, generating $\mathrm{NADPH}$.  All of this is facilitated by Ferredoxin-$\mathrm{NADP^{+}}$ reductase.

Sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferredoxin%E2%80%94NADP(%2B)_reductase

http://www.bio.davidson.edu/Courses/Bio111/NADPH.html

Comment: Exactly what is your question?

Comment: This came off to me as a mechanistic question, I edited the title. I'm unsure why this was closed, though, since some good papers exist to elucidate the FNP mechanism in photosystem I.

Answer (score 3):

**OVERVIEW** (verbatim from the article)

> Plastidic ferredoxin−NADP+ reductases (FNRs) accept electrons
>   by two sequential one-electron transfer steps from two
>   molecules of the one-electron donor ferredoxin to generate
>   their fully reduced hydroquinone state, FNRrd, through the
>   formation of an intermediate neutral semiquinone form, FNRsq.
>   FNRrd then transfers both electrons as a hydride to the
>   nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide phosphate (NADP+
>   )
>   coenzyme in a single step (Figure 1A).1,2

[Theoretical Study of the Mechanism of the Hydride Transfer between Ferredoxin–NADP+ Reductase and NADP+: The Role of Tyr303](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja310331v) (Institutional access will be required!)

Basically, FNR is a flavoprotein with a stabilized FAD prosthetic group that can alternate 3 oxidation states with 0, 1 or 2 electrons. NADP+ binds in the FNR active site, and recognition of the AMP group causes a conformational change that brings the nicotinamide portion in proximity with the isoalloxazine group of the FAD. Ferredoxin is a single-electron carrier where two molecules of ferredoxin sequentially donate electrons to the FAD group that produces a hydroquinone FADH<sub>2</sub>. The actual architecture of the charge transfer complex formed in the active site mediates the formal hydride transfer that produces NADPH*. As far as I can tell, the hydride transfer occurs while the ferredoxin is still bound due to the effect electron transfer to FAD has on the pKa and protonation of a Glu312 that stabilizes NADP+ too much in the absence of ferredoxin ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=5a_pBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=nadph+release+from+fnr&source=bl&ots=vWfBmgefvI&sig=CWIQHAy7Sg1tNGzRj3JNDL33NzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3_Oi9_MrJAhVJXR4KHSC6BFkQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=nadph%20release%20from%20fnr&f=false)).

NADPH ends up getting released after the catalytic cycle.

*I'm still trying to find some more detailed information on the catalytic mechanism.